# How can I get the string which has the largest number as value among an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm stuck while I'm solving one JavaScript problem. What I don't understand is how to print out the string which has the largest number among array.

Can you help me to point out where is my problem in my code?

The description of the problem :

> Determines which day of the week had the most number of people visiting the
>    pet store. If more than one day of the week has the same, highest amount of
>    traffic, an array containing the days (in any order) should be returned.
>     (ex. ["Wednesday", "Thursday"]). If the input is null or an empty array, the function
>    should return null.
>     @param week an array of Weekday objects
>     @return a string containing the name of the most popular day of the week if there is only one most popular day, and an array of the strings containing the names of the most popular days if there are more than one that are most popular

[Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/aaayumi/pen/eGexMw?editors=1010)

The code:

```
function mostPopularDays(week) {
if (typeof week === "undefined" || week === null || week.length === 0) 
{
return null;
}
var result;
var traffic;

for (i = 0; i < week.length; i++) {
if (week[i].traffic > traffic) {
    traffic = week[i].traffic;
    result = week[i].name;
}
}
return result;
}

function Weekday(name, traffic) {
    this.name = name;
    this.traffic = traffic;
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: var traffic;    traffic would be undefined in the for loop

Comment: You define `var result` and `var traffic` twice. When you assign to them in the `for` loop, you shouldn't write `var` again. Also, your code will be much more readable and easier to find the bug in if you indent it correctly. You can use a tool like [Prettier](https://prettier.io/playground/) to clean it up.

Comment: thanks you for the comments @marvel308 and @ Rory O'Kane. I removed 'var' in the loop but it doesn't work yet..  I created a [codepen demo](https://codepen.io/aaayumi/pen/eGexMw?editors=1010). I modified the code with Prettier.

Comment: traffic needs to have an initial value, try `var traffic = 0`

Comment: @diedu thanks. I fixed it. then I put `mostPopularDays({"Wednesday" : 30 }, {"Thursday" : 20})` in console.log and I got still `undefined`..

Answer (score 0):

When you declare `var traffic;` then `traffic === undefined` and same thing for result.

In the for loop, you compare `week[i].traffic > traffic`

It's interpreted as `week[i].traffic > undefined`

`30 (or any number) > undefined` will always be false, so you never set traffic or result to anything and it's why it returns undefined.

So `week[i].traffic > 0`

Also, I saw you comment. You should send an array as parameter. (Not 2 parameters)

Like that: `mostPopularDays([{"Wednesday" : 30 }, {"Thursday" : 20}])`

Instead of `mostPopularDays({"Wednesday" : 30 }, {"Thursday" : 20})`

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I edit my answer according to your advice, [demo](https://codepen.io/aaayumi/pen/eGexMw?editors=1010). Still it does not work.